# Will setproctitle cause proc/PID/cmdline to include env vars?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, proc

Process could use `setproctitle(3)` to update /proc/PID/cmdline, but when will `strnlen(buffer, res)` return `len` is less than `res` in [this line](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.31/fs/proc/base.c#L273)?

Another question is if `len` is equal to `res`, so env vars will be included in /proc/PID/cmdline?

Answer (score 0):

1. `strnlen` counts the number of characters in `buffer`, up to `res`. That means that it will never attempt to count beyond `buffer[res]`. However, if the length of the string is less than `res` then the returned value, `len` will be less than `res`.
2. if `len` is equal to `res`, then the kernel will need to make room for a larger name.

Comment: Could you explain [this code](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88679/54384) to me? Which branch will go [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.31/fs/proc/base.c#L273)?